Stacking gtsummary flextable objects
I am attempting to create a single table by concatenating at least two gtsummary tbl_cross tables on the col variable. Once I create the tbl_cross tables, I then convert the tbl_cross objects to flextable & add flextable formatting arguments.
When I use the flextable(rbind(...)) function below, I find that the resulting table is stacked the way I want, but none of the formatting features of the original tables are conserved.
Is there a better method to stack at least two tbl_cross tables while conserving their respective flextable formatting?
Thank you.
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, gtsummary, flextable)

t1 <- mtcars %>%
  tbl_cross(row=cyl, col=vs, percent = "column", margin="row", digits = c(0,1)) %>%
  #convert to flextable
  as_flex_table() %>%
  #I would add options below to further format the new flextable
  hline(part = "header", i = 1, border = officer::fp_border(width = 0)) %>%
  hline(part = "header", i = 1, border = officer::fp_border(width = 1.5), j = 2:3) %>%
  compose(i = 1, j = 2:3, as_paragraph("N (%)")) %>%
  compose(i = 1, j = 1, as_paragraph("Cylinder")) %>%
  ##Add footnote
  footnote( i = 1, j = 2:3,
            ref_symbols = "a",
            value = as_paragraph("Column percents"))
t1

https://i.imgur.com/iS18iux.png

t2 <- mtcars %>%
  tbl_cross(row=gear, col=vs, percent = "column", margin="row", digits = c(0,1)) %>%
  #convert to flextable
  as_flex_table() %>%
  #I would add options below to further format the new flextable
  hline(part = "header", i = 1, border = officer::fp_border(width = 0)) %>%
  hline(part = "header", i = 1, border = officer::fp_border(width = 1.5), j = 2:3) %>%
  compose(i = 1, j = 2:3, as_paragraph(as_chunk("N (%)"))) %>%
  compose(i = 1, j = 1, as_paragraph(as_chunk("Gears"))) %>%
  ##Add footnote
  footnote( i = 1, j = 2:3,
            ref_symbols = "a",
            value = as_paragraph("Column percents"))
t2

https://i.imgur.com/ZL9r7qe.png

flextable(rbind(t1$body$dataset, t2$body$dataset))

https://i.imgur.com/okQwMpe.png
Created on 2024-12-17 with reprex v2.1.1

You'll need to stack them with tbl_stack() before you convert them to flextable

This works - thank you! I also found converting them with as_gt() also works!
